# UDK: Animating characters with weapons

Tags: 3d, animation, udk, character, skeletal-animation

I imported a custom character and a pistol model to UDK and both work, but the pistol doesn't appear with the animation of the pistol when I shoot or reload... Also, the character doesn't change its animation from its normal posture to the posture animation holding a pistol.

How can I set the character to change the character's animations to animate correctly when holding a weapon? Can I do this in Unreal Kismet or do I need code?

I don't know UnrealScript well; only C++. :/

**PS**: On AnimSet, the character's posture is correct with a pistol, walking, firing, reloading, everything.

Comment: have you added sockets for weapon placement? also have you applied the textures correctly - from memory you need to have use an existing character class then rename with your new assets - http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/UDKCustomCharacters.html

Comment: @MephistonX You should make that an answer, since it seems to have been just the thing.

Answer (score 1):

Couple things you can try, first try adding sockets to your character for helping weapon holding/animation.

Then find and existing character class and copy it, then rename the folders/files with your new characters parts.

Find out more about the process here - [UDK Custom Characters](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/UDKCustomCharacters.html)